# GET Request parameters using Volley

Tags: android, facebook, rest, android-volley

I'm making an Android App that integrates with the Facebook API and uses a REST API, so I'm using Volley. However, I'm trying to issue a GET request for a JSON Array, and have to include the Facebook Authorization token in order to access the server. Most of the questions I've seen on this are relatively old, and it seems like Volley now provides support to pass in request params (from the volley github page):

```
 /**
 * Creates a new request.
 * @param method the HTTP method to use
 * @param url URL to fetch the JSON from
 * @param jsonRequest A {@link JSONArray} to post with the request. Null is allowed and
 *   indicates no parameters will be posted along with request.
 * @param listener Listener to receive the JSON response
 * @param errorListener Error listener, or null to ignore errors.
 */
public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray jsonRequest,
                        Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, (jsonRequest == null) ? null : jsonRequest.toString(), listener,
            errorListener);
}
```

But when I make and issue a JsonArrayRequest, I get a com.android.volley.AuthFailureError. Here is my code, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    System.out.println("Yo im here");
    JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray paramArray = new JSONArray();
    try {
        requestParams.put("Authorization", "JWT (Facebook auth token)");
        paramArray.put(requestParams);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println(paramArray.toString());

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            GET_MAP_MICS,
            paramArray,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray micArray) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < micArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonobject = micArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            int micId = jsonobject.getInt("micId");
                            String status = jsonobject.getString("status");
                            System.out.println("Good so far!");
                            double venLat = jsonobject.getDouble("venueLat");
                            double venLong = jsonobject.getDouble("venueLat");
                            System.out.println("got here, check it: " + venLat);
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`GET` method don't take parameters only `POST`will

in your case your passing Headers as body for `GET` method you have pass headers

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, (JSONObject) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
                /*Add your headers here*/
                return super.getHeaders();
            }
        };
```

final possibility there is two same class name will be there in your project for example any lib your using also using volley lib this happens once for me

Comment: Thanks for this, I had mistaken the distinction between parameters and Headers. However the way you posted isn't a valid way to override the getHeaders method, what would be the correct way to override that method?

Comment: there is only way pass headers is like this for any `req` in `volley` by using `Map<String, String>` if there is other method let me know if you find it

Comment: No I just mean I get a syntax error when trying to add in your Override of getHeaders